# Definition for Facebook Error Code =190 Subcode = 2069032

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

Does anyone know the what facebook graph api response (error code =190, subcode = 2069032), specifically what the **subcode** means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you're using the wrong token type (User token, page token,...)

The error code **190** is about [access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/error-handling), but with the subcode **2069032** seems more related to the token you're using. I can replicate the scenario using the wrong token type for the related API call, as example:

```
{
   "error":{
      "message":"Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token",
      "type":"OAuthException",
      "code":190,
      "error_subcode":2069032,
      "is_transient":false,
      "error_user_title":"User Access Token Is Not Supported",
      "error_user_msg":"This method must be called with a Page Access Token for New Page Experience",
   }
}
```

So double check in the docs you're using the right token type for the API Calls you're made.